# passing parameter to gulp task

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have the following gulp file :-

```
"use strict";

const gulp = require("gulp");
const clean = require("gulp-clean");
const tap = require("gulp-tap");
const tslint = require("gulp-tslint");
const typescript = require("gulp-typescript");
const util = require("gulp-util");
const tsconfig = require("./tsconfig.json");

function timeStamp() {
    let now = new Date();
    let date = [now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 1, now.getDate()];
    let time = [now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds()];

    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (time[i] < 10) {
            time[i] = "0" + time[i];
        }
        if (date[i] < 10 ) {
            date[i] = "0" + date[i];
        }
    }
    return date.join("") + "-" + time.join("");
}

gulp.task("prodClean", function() {
    return gulp
        .src("../prod/**/*", {read: true})
        .pipe(clean({force: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("../backup/build/prod-" + timeStamp()));     
});

gulp.task("prodCompile", function() {
    return gulp
        .src(tsconfig.files)
        .pipe(tap(function(file) {
             util.log(util.colors.white("compiling ") + util.colors.yellow(file.path));
         }))
        .pipe(tslint({formatter: "verbose"}))
        .pipe(tslint.report())
        .pipe(typescript(tsconfig.compilerOptions))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("../prod"));
});

let cleanEnv = function(env) {
    return gulp
        .src("../" + env + "/**/*", {read: true})
        .pipe(clean({force: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("../backup/build/" + env + "-" + timeStamp()));    
};

let buildEnv = function(env) {
    return gulp
        .src(tsconfig.files)
        .pipe(tap(function(file) {
            util.log(util.colors.white("compiling ") + util.colors.yellow(file.path));
         }))
        .pipe(tslint({formatter: "verbose"}))
        .pipe(tslint.report())
        .pipe(typescript(tsconfig.compilerOptions))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("../" + env));
};

gulp.task("build", ["prodClean", "prodCompile"]);

gulp.task("build01", () => { cleanEnv("prod"); buildEnv("prod"); } );
```

task 'build' works fine but I am trying to reuse the code so I can pass in a string containing the build environment. I have set up two functions cleanEnv and buildEnv to do this.

however when I run **gulp build** I get the following output

```
[15:28:13] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/projects/ExpressBase/src/gulpfile.js
[15:28:13] Starting 'prodClean'...
[15:28:13] Starting 'prodCompile'...
[15:28:13] compiling /home/mfc/Desktop/projects/ExpressBase/src/index.ts
[15:28:13] compiling /home/mfc/Desktop/projects/ExpressBase/src/index1.ts
[15:28:14] Finished 'prodClean' after 1.29 s
[15:28:14] Finished 'prodCompile' after 1.28 s
[15:28:14] Starting 'build'...
[15:28:14] Finished 'build' after 16 μs
```

when I run **gulp build01**, I get

```
[15:29:33] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/projects/ExpressBase/src/gulpfile.js
[15:29:33] Starting 'build01'...
[15:29:33] Finished 'build01' after 14 ms
[15:29:33] compiling /home/mfc/Desktop/projects/ExpressBase/src/index.ts
[15:29:33] compiling /home/mfc/Desktop/projects/ExpressBase/src/index1.ts
```

Although the build seems to be producing the right results how to I fix the gulp task aborting early?

Comment: I guess you need to call the callback when you're done with your work: `gulp.task("my-task", (cb)=>{ /*do your work*/ cb();})` Or if you're returning two gulp task and you want to wait on both you need to use either the `merge` package or use `run-sequence`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mark gulp task as completed when more than one gulp streams are being executed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38086033/how-to-mark-gulp-task-as-completed-when-more-than-one-gulp-streams-are-being-exe)

Comment: @Meirion, thanks. callbacks worked.